# Get combined text of all elements

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, hxt

Snippet of my attempt (using HXT and HandsomeSoup):

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

import           Text.HandsomeSoup
import           Text.XML.HXT.Core

main = do
  let html = "<html><body><a href='a'>b</a><a href='x'>y<p>z</p></a></body></html>"
  let doc = parseHtml html
  val <- runX $ doc >>> css "a" >>> deepest getText
  print val
```

Output:

```
["b","y","z"]
```

Desired output:

```
["b","yz"]
```

Essentially I am looking for a similar function like [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) from jQuery.

Edit2: In jQuery it's literally a one-liner:

```js
const texts = $('a').map((id, e) => $(e).text()).get();
```

Comment: Your question is more likely to get answer quickly if you could make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @wizzup Yeah, you are right. Fixed it :).